# Lendo uma sequencia entre 2 e um determinado valor de x

Tags: c

Boa tarde, gostaria de saber, como posso criar um vetor que armazene uma sequencia, ou seja, caso eu queira os números entre 2 e x e o usuário entre com x = 10, os valores dentro do vetor ficam como vetor[2 , 10] = 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considerando que x seja o numero fornecido pelo usuário:

```
j = 0;  //variavel que será responsável pelo indice do vetor

for (int i=2; i<=x; i++) {
    vetor[j] = i;
    j++;
}
```

Dessa forma, conforme o laço for sendo executado, o vetor ficará organizado da seguinte forma para x = 4, por exemplo:

> vetor[0] = 2;
>   vetor[1] = 3;
>   vetor[2] = 4;